# Sorting Russian/English list

Tags: php, sorting, cyrillic

I have the following array which has both English and Russian words in it:

```
[0]  => Airline_1
[1]  => Second Air
[2]  => Авиатор
[3]  => Аврора
```

I'm using the following function to sort it:

```
    uasort($newCompanyList, function ($a, $b) {
        $at = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $a);
        $bt = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $b);
        return strcmp($at, $bt);
    });
```

The expected result is this:

```
[0]  => Airline_1
[2]  => Авиатор
[3]  => Аврора
[1]  => Second Air
```

The problem is that it does sort the list, but it sorts them seperatelly, I need russian 'A' to be next to english 'A' if that makes sense. How may I achieve that?

Comment: I guess that is impossible

Comment: you cant sort a cyrilic alphabet against the greek alphabet, simply because they dont match against each other. The order is different and there are letters that vice versa dont know.

Comment: `iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', --);` doesn't support cyrillic. To translitterate cyrillic you need to build a custom function [following these rules:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian)

Comment: create a multidimensional array, where the second value is the meaning of the cyrilic word with latin characters, and sort by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try making an aggregated array of characters like:

```
$customAlfabet = array(
    'A', // EN
    'А', // RU
    'B', // EN
    'Б', // RU
    ...
);
```

Then apply the sorting based on the numeric key of the array.

```
uasort($newCompanyList, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a[0] > $b[0]) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($a[0] < $b[0]) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

It's better to apply recursion here, that if the first character is the same - check the second character, third, etc.

**NOTE**, that for example character `З` which has the equivalent sounding of `Z`, is positioned as the 9nth character in Russian alfabet, while `Z` being the last one in English,  so it's best not to do that from UX point of view.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Intl extension and Transliterator object, like so:

```
$transliterator = Transliterator::create('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII;');
uasort($newCompanyList, function ($a, $b) use ($transliterator) {
    $at = $transliterator->transliterate($a);
    $bt = $transliterator->transliterate($b);
    return strcmp($at.$a, $bt.$b);
});
```

I've appended original strings to final comparison to differentiate cases where transliteration of russian string and latin one produce the same transliteration.

Comment: Considering that `Transliterator` is horrible when working with Russian words, it's not the best approach. `А` and `Я` are the first and last letters of the Russian alfabet and both are transliterated to English 'a', while the true sounding of 'Я` is somewhat like 'ya'.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Just tested 'Ямал' and it produced 'amalt'. Disappointing. So looks like in this and similar cases manual transliteration is better approach. Still for more general uses I haven't found any other tool doing better transliteration. I mean when one needs to support not only English/Russian, but also other languages, when writing manual transliteration tables is cumbersome.

Comment: true, it's just transliteration is best for reading unknown characters. It has it's use cases with this being just an exception. Though, there are better transliteration libraries for Russian, if you might need them, [here is](http://habrahabr.ru/post/187778/) a good one (article in Russian, but the code is not :))